# Erro no SSIS: Cannot load script for execution

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

Ao executar a carga de dados gera o seguinte erro: "Cannot load script for execution".

A carga de dados executa um Script Task. Nesse Script buscar um arquivo CSV, na qual pega a data da ultima modificação e guarda em outra variável.

```
 public void Main()
    {
        System.IO.FileInfo theFile =
              new System.IO.FileInfo(Dts.Variables["User::FilePath"].Value.ToString());

        if (theFile.Exists)
        {
            Dts.Variables["User::FileDateModified"].Value = theFile.LastWriteTime;
        }
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Executando pelo VS funciona 100%, mas executando a carga pelo MS gera o erro.

Atulizamos recentemente o servidor do DW, também alteramos o SQL Server para 2016.

Tem alguma forma para resolver o erro?
Tem outra forma de pegar a data da útlima modificação da carga de dados?

Comment: parece um erro classico de path, não encontrou o arquivo no local esperado

Comment: Validei o caminho. Tudo certo em relação a isso.

Comment: Dá uma [olhada aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo?view=netframework-4.8), veja se ajuda.

Comment: No solution explorer Clique com o botão direito no seu projeto SSIS escolha Properties->Configuration Properties->TargetServerVersion->SQL Server 2016

Comment: Alterei o código de acordo com o Link do Ivan Ferrer e não resolveu. E também já alterei a versão para 2016 como sugerido pelo Augusto Vasques que também não resolveu.